# Pass Word Document Credentials in C# code

Tags: ms-word

I am using following code to access word document contents.However when I run below code each time it is keep on asking credential even though I gave password in the code.

```
Document newDocument =
         wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"<LocalPath>",
                                        confirmConversions: false,
                                        addToRecentFiles: false,
                                        readOnly: false,
                                        passwordDocument: "<Password>");
```